# can I change my user name, retaining reputation?

Tags: support, user-profile

Well, it's all in the title.

I reached 10K on StackOverflow and I'd really like to refresh my profile, adding some personal info.

I've done some search, without luck so far...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are identified to a particular Stack Exchange site by your **user id** on that site.

You can change your user name without fear of losing your reputation. The only restriction is that you can't change it again for 30 days - so choose wisely.

Go to your profile page - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/39058/chac (for example) and click on the "edit" button. This is on a per site basis so unless you use the "copy to other sites" button at the bottom of the page. Be warned - if you have any different information on other sites (profile, e-mail) this will overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm going to using my last name and initial, so I front little choice...Do you know where is the user interface to act the change? It's not apparent to me...

Comment: @chac - see update.

Comment: I'm really blind, sometime. Thanks again